# How do I "Round" or format the numbers within a arraylist for output

Tags: java

So I have a arraylist that when printed comes up with numbers like `[9.07383664881307314, 37.502809209806364E-4]`

It is not a big deal and I don'e need to format them but I would like them to be something like [9.07, 37.50]

I am using the `system.out.println (MyArrayList);`

Also I am using `java.text.DecimalFormat;` for other numbers but I am not sure if I can or how to use it for arrayLists.

can someone help me?

Comment: Is a `for` loop too complicated (because if so, i understand)?

Comment: How about a for loop and `System.out.printf("%.2f", number)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to access individual elements of your list.

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
String output = myFormatter.format(myList.get(0));
System.out.println("This is it: " + output);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way with DecimalFormat:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String [] args  )
    {
            ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

            list.add( 9.07383664881307314 );
            list.add( 37.502809209806364E-4 );

            System.out.println( list  );

            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat( "##.######" );

            for( double num : list )
            {
               System.out.println( format.format( num ) );
            }
    }
}
```

Result shows the pre-formatted values and post-formatted:

```
[9.073836648813073, 0.0037502809209806363]
9.073837
0.00375
```

Recall that the second number is E-4, so it will be less than 1, hence it isn't formatted like 37.502.  For that, you will need to handle all of the numbers in a similar fashion for comparison purposes (ex:  multiply them by 10,000 for 37.6.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a very simple approach:

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    double value = 3.141592653589793;

    //The 0 are representing the digits you want to have
    value = (double) Math.round(value * 100d) / 100d;

    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This would print out:

```
3.14
```

So in your case round them before you intert them to your `List`:

```
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    valueToInsert = (double) Math.round(valueToInsert * 100d) / 100d;

    list.add(valueToInsert);
```

...or afterwards

```
    valueRetreived = list.get(index);

    valueRetreived = (double) Math.round(valueRetreived * 100d) / 100d;

    System.out.println(valueRetreived);
```